# How to download entire repository from Github using R?

Tags: r, github, download, repository

Is it possible to download an entire repository from Github using R? These files I want to access are NOT .csv files (which most tutorials teach). They are a mix of .r and .rmd files, which I want to read into R either separately or all at once. 
Thanks :)

Comment: This is pretty vague. You can download the full repo's zip using `download.files()` (probably) or `httr::GET()` and pull files out of the local version using `unzip()` and possibly `source()` (for .R) or `rmarkdown::render()` (for .Rmd) but a specific answer would depend on exactly what the repo looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I still get stuck somehow. Indeed downloading the entire zip file would be the first step. Here's what I've tried so far: `url <- "https://github.com/jumpingrivers/meetingsR.git/"
destfile <- "meetingsR-master.zip"
download.file(url, destfile)
unzip("meetingsR-master.zip")` This however doesn't work. It seems like it does not correctly download the zip, If I try to extract it by hand it gives an error. If I download the zip by hand, it all works fine (so the .zip itself is not broken), but I of course want to automatize this step ;)

Comment: The URL you want for that repo is `"https://github.com/jumpingrivers/meetingsR/archive/master.zip"` (see the green "Clone or download" button).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Overview

You can download an entire repository from GitHub using R in three steps:

1. Copy the .zip URL from the `Clone or download` button on the [GitHub repository of interest](https://github.com/jumpingrivers/meetingsR). Be sure to copy the link address from [`Download ZIP`](https://github.com/jumpingrivers/meetingsR/archive/master.zip) and not the [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) URL.

*Note: This step assumes you are interested in the `main` branch of the GitHub repository of interest. If this is not the case, [be sure to navigate to the branch you are interested in downloading](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/). Please note that `main` is now the default name of the main branch of a GitHub repository. For more context, please [read this article by Alexis Moody hosted on DEV](https://dev.to/afrodevgirl/replacing-master-with-main-in-github-2fjf) and [this article by GitHub](https://github.com/github/renaming#renaming-the-default-branch-from-master).*

[image]

2. Paste the .zip URL into the `url` parameter of [`download.file()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) to download the .zip file of interest. Since this is a GitHub repository, it is helpful to assign the `destfile` parameter the same name as the repository of interest (in this case, `destfile = "meetingsR-master"`). The "-master" portion of the `destfile` parameter name comes from declaring the branch name of the repository of interest that you wish to download.

   - *Note: please see note in step one to understand why you might need to replace "master" with the term "main"*.
3. Use [`unzip()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/unzip.html) to unzip the downloaded .zip file.

## Reproducible Example

Be mindful to change the file paths when using the code down below.

```
# set working directory so I know where the .zip file will be located
setwd(dir = "/some/path/")

# download a .zip file of the repository
# from the "Clone or download - Download ZIP" button
# on the GitHub repository of interest
download.file(url = "https://github.com/jumpingrivers/meetingsR/archive/master.zip"
                                   , destfile = "meetingsR-master.zip")

# unzip the .zip file
unzip(zipfile = "meetingsR-master.zip")

# set the working directory
# to be inside the newly unzipped 
# GitHub repository of interest
setwd(dir = "/some/path/meetingsR-master/")

# examine the contents
list.files()
# [1] "_book"                                
# [2] "_output.yml"                          
# [3] "01-events.Rmd"                        
# [4] "02_useR_groups_aaa.Rmd"               
# [5] "02_useR_groups_asia.Rmd"              
# [6] "02_useR_groups_europe.Rmd"            
# [7] "02_useR_groups_middle_east_africa.Rmd"
# [8] "02_useR_groups_north_america.Rmd"     
# [9] "02_useR_groups_oceania.Rmd"           
# [10] "02_useR_groups_south_america.Rmd"     
# [11] "03-Rladies.Rmd"                       
# [12] "css"                                  
# [13] "deploy.sh"                            
# [14] "DESCRIPTION"                          
# [15] "docs"                                 
# [16] "index.Rmd"                            
# [17] "inverse.png"                          
# [18] "logo.png"                             
# [19] "Makefile"                             
# [20] "NAMESPACE"                            
# [21] "R"                                    
# [22] "README.md"                            
# [23] "Rmeetings.Rproj"

# end of script #
```

Answer (score 8):

I see this question has the `rstudio` tag. You can use `rstudio` (and avoid the command-line) by selecting <kbd>file</kbd> -> <kbd>new project</kbd> -> <kbd>version control</kbd> -> <kbd>git</kbd> and entering the address of your desired Github repository in the `Repository URL` field.

After you hit the `Create Project` button, `rstudio` will download the contents of the repository, create a new project, and change your working directory to the new project.

See http://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html#clone-the-new-github-repository-to-your-computer-via-rstudio

Answer (score 3):

You can download an entire repository from GitHub using R by installing the package `usethis`:

> install.packages('usethis')

Copy the .git URL from the Clone or download button on the GitHub repository of interest. Be sure to copy the link address from Download ZIP and not the HTTPS URL.

For example, I want to download this [repository](https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial). I will copy the link address from Download ZIP (https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial.git) and paste it in `usethis::use_course()` and then remove the **.git** and replace it with **/archive/master.zip**

> usethis::use_course('https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial/archive/master.zip')

You then follow the prompt question from R about where to save the file.